# Map a class to temporary class (without some of the properties)

Tags: c#

I have a class User.

I have created a generic CSV exporter that works on any type IEnumerable. It checks the class and exports all of its properties.

In the class User i dont want some of the properties to export (like password etc).

I know there is a mapper of some kind that allows to create a temp class and define the properties from the original class... i cant seem to find any exaple.

regards !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to project an `IEnumerable<User>` (let's call it `userList`) to a new `IEnumerable` with only some of the properties:

```
var query = userList.Select(u => new { u.Name, u.Address, u.Phone });
```

Now `query` will be an `IEnumerable<'a>` (anonymous type) which only contains the `Name`, `Address` and `Phone` properties from your `User` objects.

Comment: yes thats what i was looking for. Thanx to all for your anwsers !

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by the other answerers is a possible solution, but here’s another. You can declare a custom attribute:

```
class CsvIgnoreAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Then mark the fields you don’t want using this attribute:

```
class User {
    public string UserName;    // no attribute

    [CsvIgnore]
    public string Password;    // will be ignored
}
```

Then extend your CSV Exporter so that it recognises this attribute and ignores those fields marked with the attribute:

```
if (field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CsvIgnoreAttribute), true).Any())
    continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in C#

```
var userToSerialize = new { Name = user.Name, AddressLine1 = user.AddressLine1 }; // and so on...
csvExporter.Export(userToSerialize);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define anonymous ('temp') types in C#, however you can't return these or pass them to other methods without casting them to `object`.

It might be worth looking at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), which is a great library for mapping properties in one object type to another:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserInfo>();
var dataToExport = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<User>, IEnumereable<UserInfo>>(userList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `User` class, and you want to export only parts of it, you could define a `UserExport` class

```
public class UserExport
{
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

and then use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to map from `User` to `UserExport`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserExport>();
```

and then use it to map the properties

```
UserExport export = Mapper.Map<User, UserExport>(user);
```

Now you have a `UserExport` class which you can write out to your CSV. AutoMapper will deal with all the intricasies of mapping properties from one class to the other.

I am well aware you can also do this with anonymous types as many others have suggested, and it will work just fine. In same cases, you might find it more useful to have an actual type, though - you can pass that type to a procedure as a parameter type and a few more things.